# How to halt code execution while waiting for server to finish processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I know this question has been asked a lot of time but none of the solution that I've found on Stack Overflow works. So, basically, I have a table with a button to toggle the field to "on" or "off". I do this through PUT request via jQuery .ajax() method and after a successful call, I refresh the table. However, *most of the time*, the table is not up-to-date until I manually refresh the table again.

So this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function reloadTable(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "localhost/switch-list", 
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                data.forEach(function(element) {
                    /** 
                    Populate table with switch data and 
                    dynamically generate toggle button.
                    **/
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $(".toggle-switch-state").click(function(){

        var oldState = $(this).data('switch-state');
        var switchID = $(this).data('switch-id');

        if (oldState=="on") {
            newState = "off";
        }
        else{
            newState = "on";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "localhost/switch-list/"+switch_id,
            type: "PUT",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("switch_state", newState);
            },
            success: function(html){
                $("#switch-list-table").html("");
                reloadTable();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I said "*most of the time*" because sometime when the table reloads, it would show the latest value (i.e. the value after the toggle). So, I'm guessing this is some kind of "timing" issue. Which is, the javascript code does not wait for the server to finish its processing before executing the `success` block. This is further proven because it's working when I add a timeout on my `success` block:

```
$(".toggle-switch-state").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost/switch-list/"+switch_id,
        type: "PUT",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("switch_state", newState);
        },
        success: function(){
            $("#switch-list-table").html("");
            setTimeout(reloadTable, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried `async:false` but it's not working.

Comment: The problem is that the server doesn't immediately update to the new state after the request is completed. I'm not sure there is any way to handle that other than just polling the server until you see that the data has changed. You can't really rely on a hard-coded delay and there is no way to "wait" for it unless you are able to change the server-side code.

Comment: Use promises, async await. You run a function that returns a (resolve or reject), THEN you complete your action. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @Raymond do you mind providing some code? I have tried moving the code in success block into `.then()` but still not working